# Apache Camel hanging/locking up - threadsafe issue?

Tags: apache-camel

Very old project I have 'inherited', Apache 2.2.0 and apparently has never 'worked right'.

The process seems to 'lock up' occasionally and never completes. If the process is killed, files moved back to inbound, and restarted it seems to work. So it's a weird intermittent problem.

I believe the issue may be due to a custom RoutePolicy implementation;

```html
package com.company.integration.management;

import org.apache.camel.CamelContext;
import org.apache.camel.Endpoint;
import org.apache.camel.Exchange;
import org.apache.camel.Route;
import org.apache.camel.SuspendableService;
import org.apache.camel.component.seda.SedaEndpoint;
import org.apache.camel.impl.ThrottlingInflightRoutePolicy;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

public class ParserInflightRoutePolicy extends ThrottlingInflightRoutePolicy {

 private static Route fileRoute;
 
 private static final int MAX_FILES_INFLIGHT = 3;
 private static final int MSG_HIGH_WATERMARK = 100;
 private static final int MSG_LOW_WATERMARK = 25;
 
 private Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(getClass());
 
 @Override
 public void onExchangeBegin(Route route, Exchange exchange) {
  int sedaMessagesInflight = 0;

  sedaMessagesInflight = sedaQueueSize(route);
  
  if (route.getId().equalsIgnoreCase("initialRoute")) {
   fileRoute = route;
   try {
          if ((sedaQueueSize(route, "seda://parser") >= MAX_FILES_INFLIGHT) || (sedaMessagesInflight >= MSG_HIGH_WATERMARK)) {
           if ( ! ((SuspendableService)fileRoute.getConsumer()).isSuspended() ) {
            logger.error("FLOW CONTROL: stop file component");
            ((SuspendableService)fileRoute.getConsumer()).suspend();
           }
          }
   }
   catch (Exception ex) {
    logger.error("Error stopping route", ex);
   }
     }
  
  if (route.getId().equalsIgnoreCase("pricingRoute") || route.getId().equalsIgnoreCase("persistenceRoute")) {
   try {
          if ((sedaQueueSize(route, "seda://parser") == 0) && (sedaMessagesInflight <= MSG_LOW_WATERMARK)) {
           if ( ((SuspendableService)fileRoute.getConsumer()).isSuspended() ) {
            logger.error("FLOW CONTROL: start file component");
            ((SuspendableService)fileRoute.getConsumer()).resume();
           }
          }
   }
   catch (Exception ex) {
    logger.error("Error starting route", ex);
   }
     }
 }

 int sedaQueueSize(Route route) {
  int sedaMessagesInflight = 0;
  CamelContext camelContext = route.getRouteContext().getCamelContext();
  
  for (Route rte : camelContext.getRoutes()) {
         Endpoint endpoint = rte.getEndpoint();
         if (endpoint instanceof SedaEndpoint) {
          SedaEndpoint seda = (SedaEndpoint)endpoint;
          if (seda.getQueue().size() > 0) {
             sedaMessagesInflight += seda.getQueue().size();
          }
         }
     }
  logger.debug("SEDA messages inflight [" + sedaMessagesInflight + "]");
  return  sedaMessagesInflight; 
 }
 
 int sedaQueueSize(Route route, String endPointUri) {
  CamelContext camelContext = route.getRouteContext().getCamelContext();
  Endpoint endpoint = camelContext.getEndpoint(endPointUri);
  if (endpoint instanceof SedaEndpoint) {
   return ((SedaEndpoint) endpoint).getQueue().size();
  }
  return 0;
 }
 
 @Override
 public void onExchangeDone(Route route, Exchange exchange) {
  ;
 }


}
```

Notice that this code does not appear to be threadsafe - no locking mechanism as implemented in ThottlingInflightRoutePolicy. Could this be causing the intermittent issue?

Comment: Also, could it be due to the ThottlingInflightRoutePolicy.onExchangeDone() method? This class does not implement onExchangeDone, only onExchangeBegin.

Comment: When it hangs, can you force a thread dump which might give you an idea of where it is stuck?

Comment: Yes we certainly will next time it happens. Unfortunately this could be in a week, or 6 months. I want to try and fix the issue quickly without having to prove thread dumps. I was hoping someone like @clausibsen might have seen code like above before.